# How do you join records one to one with multiple possible matches ...?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table of transactions like the following

```
| ID | Trans Type | Date       | Qty | Total | Item Number | Work Order |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | Issue      | 11/27/2012 |   3 |  3.50 |        NULL |         10 |
|  2 | Issue      | 11/27/2012 |   3 |  3.50 |        NULL |         11 |
|  3 | Issue      | 11/25/2012 |   1 |  1.25 |        NULL |         12 |
|  4 | ID Issue   | 11/27/2012 |  -3 | -3.50 |         100 |       NULL |
|  5 | ID Issue   | 11/27/2012 |  -3 | -3.50 |         102 |       NULL |
|  6 | ID Issue   | 11/25/2012 |  -1 | -1.25 |         104 |       NULL |
```

These transactions are duplicates where the 'Issue's have a work order ID while the 'ID Issue' transactions have the item number. I would like to update the [Item Number] field for the 'Issue' transactions to include the Item Number. When I do a join on the Date, Qty, and Total I get something like this

```
| ID | Trans Type | Date       | Qty | Total | Item Number | Work Order |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | Issue      | 11/27/2012 |   3 |  3.50 |         100 |         10 |
|  1 | Issue      | 11/27/2012 |   3 |  3.50 |         102 |         10 |
|  2 | Issue      | 11/27/2012 |   3 |  3.50 |         100 |         11 |
|  2 | Issue      | 11/27/2012 |   3 |  3.50 |         102 |         11 |
|  3 | Issue      | 11/25/2012 |   1 |  1.25 |         104 |         12 |
```

The duplicates are multiplied! I would like this

```
| ID | Trans Type | Date       | Qty | Total | Item Number | Work Order |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | Issue      | 11/27/2012 |   3 |  3.50 |         100 |         10 |
|  2 | Issue      | 11/27/2012 |   3 |  3.50 |         102 |         11 |
|  3 | Issue      | 11/25/2012 |   1 |  1.25 |         104 |         12 |
```

Or this (Item Number is switched for the two matches)

```
| ID | Trans Type | Date       | Qty | Total | Item Number | Work Order |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | Issue      | 11/27/2012 |   3 |  3.50 |         102 |         10 |
|  2 | Issue      | 11/27/2012 |   3 |  3.50 |         100 |         11 |
|  3 | Issue      | 11/25/2012 |   1 |  1.25 |         104 |         12 |
```

Either would be fine. What would be a simple solution?

Comment: Are you sure that's a safe join condition?  Is there _anything_ better, or more unique?  If nothing else, you're attempting to tie records into an existing 'work order', which may _not_ be correct (and could open you up to legal issues).

Comment: It doesn't happen very often that all the fields are equal for two different transaction on two different work orders, but in that case it does not matter which transactions get matched up. The information is the same and the ID has no meaning except to identify a record in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to filter same results out or you could partition your results to get the first item in each grouping.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code to illustrate the partition approach.

```
SELECT ID, [Trans Type], [Date], [Qty], [Total], [Item Number], [Work Order]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ID, [Trans Type], [Date], [Qty], [Total], [Item Number], [Work Order], ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY ID, [Trans Type], [Date], [Qty], [Total]
             ORDER BY [Item Number]) AS ItemRank
    FROM YourTable
) AS SubQuery
WHERE ItemRank = 1
```